# Wordpress custom route endpoints, 404 and 500 errors

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

i am working on a wordpress plugin that uses custom rest api routes. I have one function which uses GET and one which uses POST both callabacks have been registered. I can see the endpoints listed when i navigate to localhost/mysitename/wp-json/wpgpt/v1. When I navigate to testbubby or make a GET request in postman I receive: {
"code": "rest_invalid_handler",
"message": "The handler for the route is invalid.",
"data": {
"status": 500
}
} when i navigate to send-message I get 404 (But i think this is just because it only takes a post request) but when I make a POST request in postman i receive  500 error still.

This is my php code, register_wpgpt_api_routes() is called during construct.

```
function register_wpgpt_api_routes() {
    register_rest_route(
        'wpgpt/v1', 
        '/send-message', 
        array(
        'methods'  => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'send_message',
        'permission_callaback' => '__return_true'
    ));
    register_rest_route('wpgpt/v1', '/testbubby', array(
        'methods'  => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'test_route',
        'permission_callaback' => '__return_true'
    )
);
    
}

function test_route(){
    echo "hey there";
}


function send_message( string $message ): string {    
    $messages = [];

    if( isset( $this->system_message ) ) {
        $messages[] = [
            "role" => "system",
            "content" => $this->system_message,
        ];
    }
    //$messages = array_merge( $messages, $this->message_history );

    $messages[] = [
        "role" => "user",
        "content" => $message,
    ];

    return $this->make_api_request( $messages );
}
```

This is the JS function which is supposed to make the request but I get 404 when i click the button to execute it (But i can see the payload in my network tab):

```
 function wpgpt_send_message() {
    let message = $(".wpgpt-chat-input").val();
    wpgpt_add_message( message, "user" );
    $(".wpgpt-chat-input").val("");

    let payload = {
        "message": message,
        "message_history": wpgpt_message_history
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: '/wp-json/wpgpt/v1/send-message',
        method: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify( payload ),
        success: function( response ) {
            wpgpt_add_message( response.message, "assistant" );
            wpgpt_message_history.push( {
                "role": "user",
                "content": message,
            } );
            wpgpt_message_history.push( {
                "role": "assistant",
                "content": response.message.replace( "\n", "<br>" ),
            } );
        },
        error: function() {
            wpgpt_add_message( "Sorry, there was an error", "assistant" );
        }
      });
}
```

Appreciate any assistance, this is my first time trying to use the custom endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Please read this entire page from the WordPress Docs: [Adding Custom Endpoints](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/)

You will see that the first argument passed into the `callback` is a [WP_REST_Request](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/#arguments) object. The `send_message()` function expects a string as the first argument.

You will also learn that the `callback` should [return](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/#return-value) a value (e.g. PHP associative array) that can be serialized into a JSON string (which is done automatically by WordPress) to be returned to the client. The `test_route()` function is *echo*-ing content rather than **return**-ing a value.

Another helpful page to read is [Routes and Endpoints](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/routes-and-endpoints/).

Answer (score 0):

In your function 'send_message' you need to return a rest response with your data and http status code

```
return new WP_REST_Response( array( 'message' => 'Ok' ), 200 );
```